# make & make install OpenSSL 1.0.1e some error

Tags: openssl

> duplicate symbol _OPENSSL_cleanse in:
>
> ../libcrypto.a(mem_clr.o)
>
> ../libcrypto.a(x86_64cpuid.o)
>
> duplicate symbol _AES_encrypt in:
>
> ../libcrypto.a(aes_core.o)
>
> ../libcrypto.a(aes-x86_64.o)
>
> duplicate symbol _AES_decrypt in:
>
> ```
> ../libcrypto.a(aes_core.o)
> ```
>
> ../libcrypto.a(aes-x86_64.o)
>
> duplicate symbol _private_AES_set_encrypt_key in:
>
> ../libcrypto.a(aes_core.o)
>
> ../libcrypto.a(aes-x86_64.o)
>
> duplicate symbol _private_AES_set_decrypt_key in:
>
> ../libcrypto.a(aes_core.o)
>
> ../libcrypto.a(aes-x86_64.o)
>
> duplicate symbol _AES_cbc_encrypt in:
>
> ../libcrypto.a(aes_cbc.o)
>
> ../libcrypto.a(aes-x86_64.o)
>
> ld: 6 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>
> make[2]: *** [link_app.] Error 1
>
> make[1]: *** [openssl] Error 2
>
> make: *** [build_apps] Error 1

`iOS 6.1.0 and Xcode 4.6.1

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you have compiled and linked both assembly and .c files. Either use assembly or .c files, not both.

Please read the README or some documents to build the library on Mac OS X.